# How to get a JSON response from a POST form using Django

Tags: json, django, forms, python-2.7, api

I'm trying to use the [API](https://zermelo.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DEV) of [zermelo](http://www.zermelo.com/).
I am using a "Djangofied" version of this form to get the Authorization code.

```
<form action="https://helios.zportal.nl/api/v2/oauth/token" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code"/>
<input type="text" name="code"/>
<input type="submit" value="POST"/>
</form>
```

I do get the code in a JSON file but

1. The JSON opens in front of the user.
2. I do not know how to 'save' the JSON file and change the code to a var.

Comment: If you want the token in the server-side, you should make the post request in the python file, and if you should get it in the client-side, you can make an ajax post request and then sent it back to server!

Comment: I would like to have it server side, but how do I this kind of request in a python file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from the api documentation, you should send a application code and get the token. So, let `authorization_code` be your app code.

```
import requests
r = requests.post("https://helios.zportal.nl/api/v2/oauth/token", data={'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'code': *Authorization Code*})
```

`r.text` get you the responded text from the server.

Comment: The JSON works, but when i'm trying to authenticate I get the following error: `class org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'code' is not present` When looking at the form, the authorization_code has a name of "code" so I think that the name has to be included in some way. But I have no clue how.

Comment: I cannot understand where you face the problem! If with the above solution you can communicate with the server api and get JSON response, then you should follow the server instruction to use the api methods.

Comment: According to the example on the documentation, there should be `&code=THE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE` at the end of the data. But I don't know how to format this correctly in python/django.

Comment: Pass it as another data. `data={'grant_type': 'sth1', 'code':'sth2'}`